# How to handle ObjectResult in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

In Entity Framework 4, I'm facing a problem when I use function import to a stored procedure and then using as a scalar value.  It generates the code below:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> GetTopEmployee()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>("GetTopEmployee");
}
```

How do I use the return value of this method?

For example, this code works fine:

```
NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
var i = db.GetTopEmployee();
```

But I want to use return values only as int. If I use return value as non while in function import it give -1 as output.

When I try the code below:

```
NorthwindEntities db2 = new NorthwindEntities();
int j = db.GetTopEmployee();
```

It throws an error saying:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'int'

How do I parse the above?

Comment: What is the code that gives `-1` as output? I don't understand "return value as non while in function import".

Comment: I mean if retune my stored procedure through function import and then mark the return value as none, then it gives me -1 as output

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Notice that the return type of `GetTopEmployee` is an `ObjectResult<Nullable<int>>`. `ObjectResult<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so your method is capable of returning more than one `Nullable<int>`.

I assume you are trying to get some form of Id for the employee. If you are absolutely sure you are only going to get one result you could use the following code to get that Id.

```
  var topId = db.GetTopEmployee().FirstOrDefault();
```

`topId` could be null. You will have to use `topId.Value` or `var result = topId ?? -1;` to get an int result.

```
  NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
  int j = db.GetTopEmployee().FirstOrDefault() ?? -1;
```

Comment: If you are absolutely sure you are going to get one result, you should use `db.GetTopEmployee().First()`, or put differently, use this if you want to receive an exception if no results were returned.