# c# , Entity Framework Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework. 
I have the following:

```
var db = new LikEntities();

GetParamAlerts_Result paramRslt = db.GetParamAlerts();
```

`GetParamAlerts` is a stored procedure and it is of type

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<GetParamAlerts_Result>
```

Note the GetParamAlerts returns multiple rows.

When I run the code above I the following error message :

> Cannot implicitly convert type:
>
> 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'PVT_Alert_Notification.GetParamAlerts_Result'

Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Linq to SQL is not the same as LINQ to Entities. Is this Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL?

Comment: This is Entity Framework

Comment: @NatePet, are you returning an `IList<GetParamAlerts_Result>` from this method?

Comment: @NatePet, it would be also helpful to tell us what the desired result is i.e. do you only want one object? do you want a collection? etc.  The code above suggest you want one object, your comments suggest you want a list, so it's confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Entity Framework cannot guarantee that your stored procedure will **always** return a single row, so it's put into a `ObjectResult` which [is just an enumerable collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739113.aspx). If you're always expecting a single result, you can use `db.GetParamAlerts().Single()` to get the result as `GetParamAlerts_Result`, or use any of the standard enumerable methods like `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Steven, not that it will return multiple rows. Can you tweak the code above to reflect that. I did a ToList() but got a similar error message.

Comment: @NatePet I don't quite understand your question. Doing a `ToList()` really won't do anything to cast a collection to a single type, resulting in a similar casting error.

Comment: @NatePet `System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<GetParamAlerts_Result>` is pretty much a list already. No need for `ToList()` or anything else. Just use `GetParamAlerts_Result paramRslt = db.GetParamAlerts().Single();` and it'll work.

Comment: Steven, in my case, I am expecting more than 1 result. If I use the Single() it will return just 1 results. How can the code be tweaked to allow for multiple results.

Comment: @NatePet Then make it `ObjectResult<GetParamAlerts_Result> paramRslt = db.GetParamAlerts();` and then `paramsRslt` will have the collection of results which you can iterate over, or send onto a view.

Comment: Thanks Steven. Another question, why does it blow up when I do something like:   System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<GetParamAlerts_Result> paramRslt = db.GetParamAlerts().Where(a => a.Companyid == companyId); Without the Where it works fine.

Comment: Because `Where()` returns `IEnumerable<T>` and not `ObjectResult<T>`. If you want to cover both cases since `ObjectResult` implements IEnumerable as well, change the `paramRslt` type to `IEnumerable<GetParamAlerts_Result>`. Resulting in: `IEnumerable<GetParamAlerts_Result> paramRslt = db.GetParamAlerts().Where(a => a.Companyid == companyId);`

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you should **either** be using

```
PVT_Alert_Notification.GetParamAlerts_Result paramRslt = db.GetParamAlerts();
```

or the method is returning the wrong type?  Can you pot the code for the method? or you are getting a **collection**?

If you have a collection, you could use:

```
var result = db.GetParamAlerts();
return result.FirstOrDefault();
```

You will see a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654365/how-to-handle-object-result-in-entity-framework-4)

Answer (score 0):

try incorporating first or default at the end

```
 GetParamAlerts_Result paramRslt = db.GetParamAlerts().FirstOrDefault();
```

try using cast

```
  GetParamAlerts_Result paramRslt = db.GetParamAlerts().Cast<GetParamAlerts_Result>().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting a list. Can you kindly tweak the code to reflect that. I did a .ToList() but that did not work.