# Return GUID from stored procedure in EF5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5 and I have a stored procedure that returning a GUID. When I am using the stored procedure in the C# the EF has created a function for the stored procedure. I am calling the function and with a VAR property.

I can see the value and it is correct but I don't know how to extract it form the VAR.

SQL Server stored procedure that return value is uniqueidentifier :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetNewUser]
    @id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE webpages_Membership
    SET IsConfirmed = 0
    WHERE UserId = @id

    SELECT ClientSecretID FROM UserProfile WHERE UserId = @id
END
```

The function that the EF created :

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<System.Guid>> SetNewUser(Nullable<int> id)
{
            var idParameter = id.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("id", id) :
                new ObjectParameter("id", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<System.Guid>>("SetNewUser", idParameter);
}
```

My call for the function :

```
var userGuid = entities.SetNewUser(userId);
```

Thank you all

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to handle object result in entity framework 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654365/how-to-handle-object-result-in-entity-framework-4)

Comment: Yes very similer but his function returns int and my returns GUID, So i can`t use FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @danny Sure you can. `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't only return int. It's a generic function.

Comment: This is the exception that i am getting : "The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to a nullable 'System.Guid' type is not valid."