# Entity Framework Imported Function Return Type Not Being Updated

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a few functions in C# I generated from SQL scripts using the entity framework.  However, I need to specify a different return type for those functions.

Both functions are returning ObjectResult types, but I need to switch this to the custom data type the table generates (change it from ObjectResult to User, for example).

Currently, I'm opening the .edmx file in visual studio, right clicking and selecting "Model Browser".  Then, I locate my function under "Function Imports", highlight, and edit the return type in the properties window.  I do this by clicking on the "..." button next to return type and changing the "Returns a Collection Of" value to Entities -> User.  I click ok, but the function is still returning the previous type.

Locating the function in Model.Context.cs, I see the code has not changed.  Here's the generated function:

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<User> AddUser(string login, string consoleName, string ip, MergeOption mergeOption)
    {
        var loginParameter = login != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Login", login) :
            new ObjectParameter("Login", typeof(string));

        var consoleNameParameter = consoleName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("ConsoleName", consoleName) :
            new ObjectParameter("ConsoleName", typeof(string));

        var ipParameter = ip != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Ip", ip) :
            new ObjectParameter("Ip", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<User>("AddUser", mergeOption, loginParameter, consoleNameParameter, ipParameter);
```

I've tried manually changing the return type from "ObjectResult" to "User", but this causes an error on the return line.  Since the return line is calling the stored procedure, I'm not sure what to change it to in order to keep the procedure call working but get a different type back.

UPDATE:

In lieu of not finding an answer online, I'm now trying to edit the function manually.  Changing the return type in the function definition is easy:

```
    public virtual LogFile AddFile(string name, Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> recordedDate, string build, Nullable<long> userId, MergeOption mergeOption)
```

However, this, of course, requires the return line to be changed as well, and since the return line contains the actual call to the stored procedure, I'm not sure what I should be changing it to yet.

```
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<LogFile>("AddFile", mergeOption, nameParameter, recordedDateParameter, buildParameter, userIdParameter);
```

Comment: I think the code *did* change. It should have been `ObjectResult<AddUser_Result>` by default. You changed it into `ObjectResult<User>`. I would not tamper with this generated code. Live with it and get the `User` from the `ObjectResult` in your application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gert Arnold was correct in his comment.  The data type was initially ObjectResult< AddUser_Result > and making the change in the model browser changed it to ObjectResult< User > and I simply didn't notice the change.

I was trying to make it return a straight User, partly because I'm not familiar with ObjectResult and there didn't appear to be an obvious way to extract the User from it given the methods and properties of that class (and partly because I was told to in a code review).  I found what I really needed here:

[How to handle ObjectResult in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654365/how-to-handle-object-result-in-entity-framework-4)

Without touching the function definitions, here are my new function calls (after a lot of tweaking):

```
returnedUser = entities.AddUser(user.Login, user.ConsoleName, user.Ip).FirstOrDefault();                       // Upload the user.
returnedFile = entities.AddFile(file.Name, file.RecordedDate, file.Build, returnedUser.Id).FirstOrDefault();   // Upload the file.
```

Let's hope this satisfies some, admittedly, picky people.